# Iterating over cursor and attempt to assign this same type to nested table cause PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type. PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello I would like to get all ids, primary key, number types using cursor and write them to nested table. There is declared nested table and cursor:

```
TYPE clubsIdsArray IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    nestedclubsIdsArray clubsIdsArray:=clubsIdsArray();
    
    CURSOR clubsIds IS
    SELECT CLUB_ID
    FROM CLUB;
```

After this I wanna write this ids to nested table:

```
for i in clubsIds
LOOP

nestedclubsIdsArray.EXTEND(1);
nestedclubsIdsArray (nestedclubsIdsArray.count):= i;

END LOOP;
```

But then I get an error: **Error at line 28: PL/SQL: Statement ignored Error at line 28: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type** Obviously club_id is a type of number.     Why?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the whole cursor into it, but what the cursor returned (and that's `club_id`) - see line #11:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE clubsidsarray IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  3
  4     nestedclubsidsarray  clubsidsarray := clubsidsarray ();
  5
  6     CURSOR clubsids IS SELECT club_id FROM club;
  7  BEGIN
  8     FOR i IN clubsids
  9     LOOP
 10        nestedclubsidsarray.EXTEND (1);
 11        nestedclubsidsarray (nestedclubsidsarray.COUNT) := i.club_id;
 12     END LOOP;
 13  END;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```